# What is the NamedTuple alternative in Java?

Tags: java, python, transpiler

I am trying to turn some python code into java and one of the obstacles I have come across is the use of a namedtuple. It seems Java does not use tuples so I was wondering what could I use as an alternative.

```
#part of the python code:

@staticmethod
def stream_file(fieldnames, id):
   tuple = namedtuple("RECORD", " ".join(fieldnames))
   ...
   data = [x for x in arr]
   yield tuple._make(data)
```

Comment: is it a maven project ? if so, you can use [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-tuples) maven dependency and use Java Tuples. If not maven project then use numenta and extend either [Tuple](https://numenta.github.io/htm.java/org/numenta/nupic/util/Tuple.html) class or [NamedTuple](https://numenta.github.io/htm.java/org/numenta/nupic/util/NamedTuple.html) in your project

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map`. There are different implementations, all with different advantages.

- `HashMap` provides a Mapping based on a hash-key, which is inherent for all objects in Java.
- `TreeMap` is better, if you want to define identity by a comparable value (like a String).

Maps can by typed, but not per-value. I believe, what you are looking for is a `TreeMap<String, Object>`, which would allow you to map from a String (identifier or id) to an object. However the type of the object is then mostly anonymous, and you might need a lot of `instanceof`. However this seems to satisfy your requirement.